# custom color palette with custom breaks on stats::heatmap

Tags: r, colors, heatmap, palette

I'd like to create a clustered heatmap of my data, clustering different models and categories based on the MAPE. I'd like to apply the color palette green-white-red, in which the range of green colors (MAPE: 0-10) is smaller than the range of red colors (MAPE 10, up to 100), with a mid-value of 10.
However, when i try to do this, it results in a heatmap containing only green colors.

#### Dummy matrix - Let's say my data looks like this:

```
matrix_heatmap <- matrix(1:16, nrow=4, ncol=4, 
                         dimnames=list(c("W", "X", "Y", "Z"), 
                                         c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
matrix_heatmap
```

#### custom colorpalette and breaks

```
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "white", "red"))
number_breaks <- 6
breaks_green <- seq(from=min(matrix_heatmap), to=10, 
                    length.out=floor(number_breaks / 2))
breaks_red <- seq(from=10, to=quantile(matrix_heatmap, 0.95), 
                  length.out=ceiling(number_breaks / 2))
breaks <- unique(c(0, breaks_green, breaks_red))

custom_palette <- colors(number_breaks - 1)

custom_palette
breaks
```

```
heatmap(matrix_heatmap, 
        col=custom_palette, 
        breaks=breaks,
        cexRow=0.5, cexCol=0.5)
legend("topleft", legend=breaks, fill=custom_palette, title="legenda")
```

Comment: No clue why it works with `image(matrix_heatmap, col=colors(length(breaks) - 1), breaks=breaks)` but not with `heatmap`, even though the documentation says "additional arguments passed on to image, e.g., col specifying the colors".

Answer (score 1):

`heatmap` scales the values depending on parameter `scale`. From `?heatmap`:

> ```
> scale: character indicating if the values should be centered and
>        scaled in either the row direction or the column direction,
>        or none.  The default is ‘"row"’ if ‘symm’ false, and
>        ‘"none"’ otherwise.
> ```

So either you provide your `breaks` in a scaled version, or you ask for no-scaling:

```r
heatmap(matrix_heatmap, 
        col = custom_palette, 
        breaks = breaks,
        cexRow = .5, cexCol = .5, scale = "none")
```

[image: Heatmap using all teh colors provided]

Comment: Do you know the issue with `col=colors(length(breaks) - 1)` (which works with `image`, and `heatmap` internally uses `image`)? I wonder if this might be an inconsistency.

Comment: `col` is properly passed down, but if we scale the values they mostly fall below the smalles threshold. A long story short: `col` works as expected, but `scale != "none"` results in onlay a part of the colors used.  scaling is done in `heatmap` hence `image` without the detour via `heatmap` works as expected.